# Convergence in Probability implies subsequence converges in $L^p$

Tags: probability

Given a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converging to a random variable $X$ in probability, how can I find a sub sequence of $X_n$ converging to $X$ in $L^p$? The result seems bit weird to me without knowing $X\in L^p$.

My guess: The problem occurs in convergence in $L^p$ is that one might have large values in $X_n$ with low probability, which will distort the expectation. This effect is emphasized if we take the power to it. So I need to control these values with lower probability, such that the expectation is not distorted too much by these values. How can I realize it in mathematical terms.

Comment: If $X_n \notin L^p$ you can, in general, not expect to find such a subsequence. Just pick some $Y \notin L^p$ and set $X_n := Y/n$. Clearly, $X_n \to 0$ almost surely (hence in probability), but there does not exist a subsequence converging to $0$ in $L^p$.

Comment: @saz if we assume on $X \in L^p$? It is not so obvious for me how to find a subsequence being uniform integrable.

Comment: In the example in my previous comment we have $X=0$ which is clearly nicely integrable. Nevertheless, there does not exist a subsequence converging in $L^p$.

Comment: @saz Thanks, I see the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple. First take $p\geq 1$. Take $X_n$ such that $P(X_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and  $P(X_n=n^2)=\frac{1}{n}$. Clearly $X_n\to 0$ in probability. For $n>m$ we have:
\begin{align}
\Vert X_n-X_m\Vert_p \geq \Big| \Vert X_n\Vert_p-\Vert X_m\Vert_p\Big|
\end{align}
Moreover $\Vert X_n\Vert_p=E[|X_n|^p]^{1/p}=n^{(2p-1)/p}$. Hence:
\begin{align}
\Vert X_n-X_m\Vert_p\geq n^{(2p-1)/p}-m^{(2p-1)/p}
\end{align}
You can make $\Vert X_n-X_m\Vert_p$ arbitrary large, by just taking $n$ too large. Hence you can never find a subsequence that is Cauchy. For a convergent subsequence you must have a cauchy subsequence. So no convergent (in $L^p$) subsequence exist.

Comment: Thank you for this example.